# How to cover catch block in Messaging.SingleEmailMessage

Tags: unit-test, singleemailmessage

I have a class that sends an email notification when a partner user posts in Chatter Feed. I wrote a test class which already covers most but I'm just having some difficulty here figuring out how to cover the catch block even after checking a couple of posts online. Any help is appreciated.

Apex Class:

```
public override void onAfterInsert(){  
  Set<Id> opptyIdSet = new Set<Id>();
  Set<Id> ownerIdSet = new Set<Id>();
  Map<Id, FeedItem> OppIdtoFdItmMap = new Map<Id, FeedItem>();
  List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    
  //Get ProfileId of Community Portal users profile
  Id commUserProfId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'XXX'].Id;
  
  //Get Org-wide email address
  OrgWideEmailAddress orgwideAddress = [SELECT Id, Address, DisplayName FROM OrgWideEmailAddress WHERE Address = 'xxx@xxx.com' LIMIT 1];

  //Get related Opportunity Ids
  for(FeedItem fItem : (List<FeedItem>)Records){
      if(fItem.ParentId.getSobjectType() == Opportunity.SobjectType && UserInfo.getProfileId() == commUserProfId){
          opptyIdSet.add(fItem.ParentId);
          OppIdtoFdItmMap.put(fItem.ParentId, fItem);
      }
  }
  
  for(Opportunity opp: [SELECT Id, Name, Owner.Email from Opportunity WHERE Id IN :opptyIdSet]){
      String Recordlink = URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+opp.Id;
      String body = OppIdtoFdItmMap.get(opp.Id).Body + '<br/>';
      body += 'Record link:  ' + Recordlink + + '<br/>' + '<br/>';
      
      Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
      mail.setToAddresses(new List<String> {String.valueOf(opp.Owner.Email)});
      mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(orgwideAddress.Id);
      mail.setSubject(UserInfo.getName() + ' has posted an update on ' + opp.Name);
      mail.setHtmlBody(body);
      
      emailList.add(mail);
  }
  
  if(emailList.size() > 0){
      try{
          // Send all email notifications   
          Messaging.sendEmail(emailList,false);
      }
      catch(emailException e){
          System.debug('Encountered an Error: ' + e);
      }   
  }
```

}

Test Class:

```
@isTest
private class FeedItemsTest{
static testmethod void testEmailNotif() {
    Test.startTest();
    List<Account> accounts = TestDataFactory.createAccounts(2);
    List<Contact> contacts = TestDataFactory.createContacts(2, accounts[0].id);
    List<Contact> contactsWithAccount = TestDataFactory.mapContactsToAccount(contacts, accounts[0].Id);
    accounts[0].ParentId = accounts[1].Id;
    update accounts;
    
    contactsWithAccount[1].AccountId = accounts[1].Id;
    update contactsWithAccount;
    
    User partner = TestDataFactory.createPartnerUser('XXX', contactsWithAccount[0].id);
    
    List<Opportunity> opportunities = TestDataFactory.createOpportunities(3, accounts[0]);
    Test.stopTest();
    
    System.runAs(partner){
        List<FeedItem> posts = TestDataFactory.createFeedItems(1, opportunities[0].id);
    } 
}
```

}

Test Coverage:

[image: test coverage]

Comment: in summer 21, [Opportunities can be assigned to Queues](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DfoWAAS) in which case, there would be no email and the send should fail if you mock an Oppo owned by a Queue. Sadly, Summer 21 is not here as of your post

Answer (score 2):

There's only so much "unhappy path" testing you can do given that Salesforce doesn't allow you to arbitrarily mock out code. One option here is to make your class virtual and refactor the core piece of your class like this:

```
if(emailList.size() > 0){
  try{
    // Send all email notifications   
    sendEmail(emailList,false);
  }
  catch(emailException e){
    System.debug('Encountered an Error: ' + e);
  }   
}
```

And add a virtual method:

```
protected virtual void sendEmail(List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailList,
        Boolean allOrNothing) {
  Messaging.sendEmail(emailList, allOrNothing);
}
```

You can then create a test-local specialization of your class (I mean as an inner class of the test):

```
public with sharing class Xyz extends Abc {
    protected override void sendEmail(List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailList,
        Boolean allOrNothing) {
        throw new EmailException();
    }
}
```

All your happy path testing can use the real target class, `Abc` (whatever it is really called), but for the unhappy path test you can explicitly instantiate `Xyz` instead. That way you can cover even that single line.

That said, if your exception handler is more than a couple of statements, I personally would move that into a separate method and pass the exception and context into it. That way you can actually test the exception handler's method without actually needing to throw an exception.

Comment: +1 Also, [my answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/48095/2984) comes to mind. 100% is not a realistic goal for most code bases, nor should it be. If you can't test something, it's not testable. That said, you could take your virtual method idea one step further and use the Stub API to actually force an exception while testing.

Comment: That is absolutely true. I do think that the stub provider can be a bit confusing for some folks which is why I don't often suggest it, but it is a nice facility (somewhat like the old Java dynamic proxy).