# Test "Try and Catch" block Code

Tags: apex, code-coverage

I wrote a test class (please, see below) that covers most of my code except "catch" part of the code.
Please, help me to figure out what is missing in my apex test class.

```
public with sharing class SubmitReportUseOfAwardController {

    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static string updateUseOfAward(string recordId){

        Use_of_Award__c record=[SELECT id, UOA_Report_Status__c FROM Use_of_Award__c WHERE Id=:recordId];        
    try
    {
    
        record.UOA_Report_Status__c='Submitted';
        update record;
        
        return 'SUCCESS';
    }
        catch(Exception e){
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage()); 
    }
    }
}
```

My test class

```
@isTest
public class SubmitReportUseOfAwardCtrTest {

    @testSetup
    public static void dataInit()
    {
        Account org=new Account();
        org.Name='test';      
        insert org;
        
        Award__c award=new Award__c();
        award.Organization__c=org.Id;
        insert award;
        
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator'];
        
        User u1 = new User(Alias = 'standt1',
                        Country='USA',
                        Email='demo1@randomdemodomain.com',
                        EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8',
                        LastName='Testing',
                        LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
                        LocaleSidKey='en_US',
                        ProfileId = p.Id,
                        TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles',
                        UserName='dprobertdemo1@camfed.org');
        insert u1;
        
        Use_of_Award__c record=new Use_of_Award__c();
        record.UOA_Award__c=award.Id;
        record.Fiscal_Year_Entry__c='2020';
        record.CCME_Analyst__c=u1.Id;
        insert record;
        
    }
    
    
    @isTest
    public static void testUpdateUseOfAwardPositive()
    {
    
        
        string recordId=[SELECT Id from Use_of_Award__c LIMIT 1].id;  
        string result=SubmitReportUseOfAwardController.updateUseOfAward(recordId);
        system.assert(result=='SUCCESS');
        

    }
    @isTest
    public static void testUpdateUseOfAwardNegative()
    {
        try
        {
        SubmitReportUseOfAwardController.getUseOfAwardRecord(null);
            system.assert(false);
        }
        catch(exception e)
        {
        system.assert(true); }
    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Is `UOA_Award__c` , `Fiscal_Year_Entry__c`, or `CCME_Analyst__c` required fields on the `Use_of_Award__c` object?

Comment: Which test method are you expecting to cover your catch statement?  Can you be more specific about which exact test you're expecting to cover your catch statement, and what part of it don't you understand how it's not hitting your catch statement.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to properly cover the catch block is to somehow insert bad data and then try to update the record. Since you use a query to effectively verify the ID is valid and the user has read access to the record, your only real alternative is to create a fake user that has a limited DML operation (not System Administrator), so that the update will fail. You may choose to create a fake profile for this operation.

More generally speaking, it's almost always better to "ignore" the try-catch block if you're just worried about coverage. As I've said in past answers, such as [this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/48067/2984), 100% coverage is generally impossible for several types of code, either because it involves faking something (e.g. a failed DML operation in your case) or because it would be too time consuming. Focus on the main path of your code for coverage.

By the way, you haven't tested what would happen if the user tries to provide a fake ID, nor do you prevalidate that the user even has write access. Doing this would help increase your code coverage, and make it easier to write tests to verify that the user has appropriate permissions and isn't trying to hack your page/component.

Answer (score 0):

You should not implement a `try;catch;` block without knowing the reason for failure. If reason for failure is known, a unit test covering that risk should be designed with a single concern.

Here is an example of how you can execute the `catch` block and get an `exception`. In this case, you would expect an **Exception: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id XXXXXXXXX; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION** message.

```
@isTest
public static void testUpdateUseOfAwardNegative() {
    Account testAccount = [select id from Account];
    Use_of_Award__c record = [select id, UOA_Award__c from Use_of_Award__c];
    record.UOA_Award__c = testAccount.Id;
    try {
        SubmitReportUseOfAwardController.getUseOfAwardRecord(record.Id);
        system.assert(false);
    } catch (exception e) {
        system.assert(true); 
    }
}
```

Your `testSetup` only has a single `Account` and `Use_of_Award__c` inserted so SOQL should not return more than 1 record for both objects. By the way, the `system.assert(false)` will never fire in the `try` block.