# Write a test class to fail the upload AKA get to the catch block

Tags: unit-test, contentversion, contentdocument, upload

Currently writing a test class to fail the upload procedure but having a hard time coming up with an idea. The only way I was thinking is to make a very big input so that it exceeds the size limit of the upload but are there any other ways to make this neat and clean?

```
public ResumeDTO uploadResume(String fileBody, Id candidateId)
    {
        try
        {
            fileBody = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(fileBody, 'UTF-8');   
            ContentVersion attachmentVersion = new ContentVersion();
            attachmentVersion.ContentLocation = 'S';
            attachmentVersion.PathOnClient = 'TestFile2.txt';
            attachmentVersion.Title = 'Test File 2';
            attachmentVersion.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(fileBody);
            insert attachmentVersion;

            String attachmentVerId = [SELECT contentDocumentid FROM contentVersion WHERE id =: attachmentVersion.id]?.contentDocumentid;

            ContentDocumentLink attachmentLink = new ContentDocumentLink();
            attachmentLink.ContentDocumentId = attachmentVerId;
            attachmentLink.LinkedEntityId = candidateId;
            attachmentLink.ShareType = 'V';
            attachmentLink.visibility = 'AllUsers';
            insert attachmentLink;

            ResumeDTO toReturn = new ResumeDTO(attachmentLink,attachmentVersion.Title);
            return toReturn;
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw new SLExceptions.ProgrammingException('Attachments were not successfully uploaded. Error: -----' + ex + '-----');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd say, don't worry about it. As I [stated before](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/48095/2984), 100% coverage may be impossible in some cases, and 90%+ should be acceptable in most cases. That said, in your specific case, you could pass in an invalid url-encoded string.

```
try {
  ClassName myController = new ClassName();
  myController.uploadResume('%a',null);
  System.assert(false, 'Expected an exception from invalid data');
} catch(SLExceptions.ProgrammingException ex) {
  System.assert(ex.getMessage().contains('StringException'),'Expected invalid URL exception');
}
```

In addition, I presume passing in a null candidateId with a valid string would also get you to a similar exception, since LinkedEntityId would then be null.